# Self hosted project management software

Tags: project-management

I am trying to find a project management tool that I can install onto my local host and have multiple users have access to it.  Is this possible and does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you need to give some more information

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Currently, your question is much too broad. One more hint is to use our [search function](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=project+management+answers%3A1) (link goes to a list of 33 questions with answers on this topic).

Comment: Should it be browser based? if not, which o/s? Multiple users all sitting at your machine (localhost), or accessing it by browser, telnet, client on their PCs & database on yours?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of tools can be used to accomplish your requirement.

Take a look at: [Comparison of project management software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software)

You can order the above comparison selecting the values:

- 'Hosted on Premises=Yes' (in the 'General Information' table)
- 'Collaborative Software=Yes' (in the 'Features' table)